# How to specify ADO.NET connection timeouts of less than a second?

Tags: ado.net, sqlconnection

Connection time outs are specified in the connectionString in web.config file like this:

```
"Data Source=dbs;Initial Catalog=db;"+"Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30"
```

The time is in seconds. I want to specify a connection timeout in milliseconds, say 500ms. How can I do that?

**Edit 1:** I want to do this to create a ping method which just checks if the database is reachable or not.

**Edit 2:** I have been searching for some similar solutions and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762206/1539782) mentioned specifying timeout in milliseconds. So I was intrigued and wanted to find out how it can be done.

Comment: I's not possible(imho), so why don't you specify your ping intervals in seconds?

Comment: Added some clarification to question again.

Comment: @Animesh: Maybe you could use a `BackgroundWorker` or a [`WaitCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) to ping the database. Then there's no delay at all. Your added link makes no sense since it's not clear how you should set a `ConnectionTimeout` to 500 milliseconds when the property represents seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure that you are using non-pooled connections to ensure that you are always getting a fresh connection, you can do this by adding `Pooling=false` to your connection string. For both of these solutions I would also recommend adding `Connection Timeout=1` just to ensure that ADO.NET does not needlessly continue to open the connection after you application has given up.

For .Net 4.5 you can use the new `OpenAsync` method and a `CancellationToken` to achieve a short timeout (e.g. 500ms):

```
using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(500);
    await connection.OpenAsync(tokenSource.Token);
}
```

When this times out you should see the `Task` returned by `OpenAsync` go to the canceled state, which will result in a `TaskCanceledException`

For .Net 4.0 you can wrap the connection open in a `Task` and wait on that for the desired time:

```
var openTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
});

openTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Need to observe any exceptions here - perhaps you might log them?
    var ignored = task.Exception;
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

if (!openTask.Wait(500))
{
    // Didn't complete
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

In this example, `openTask.Wait()` will return a `bool` that indicates if the `Task` completed or not. Please be aware that in .Net 4.0 you *must* observe all exceptions thrown inside tasks, otherwise they will cause your program to crash.

If you need examples for versions of .Net prior to 4.0 please let me know.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.